# how to access different form elements in an HTML page using Angular JS without using Views of Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I am new to Angular Js and I am trying to make a Login page where I Have three forms which are as follows:

1. Login Form
2. Create New Account form
3. Forgot password Form.

All this forms are present in one HTML Page.HTML page  for the login(login.html) is as follows:

```
 <form class="login-form" ng-submit="submit()" method="POST" ng-controller="SignInController"  >
        <h3 class="form-title">Sign In</h3>
        <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
            <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
            <span>
        Enter any username and password. </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email Address</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Addresss" name="email" ng-model="email_id"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-solid placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Password" name="password" ng-model="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions"  >
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase">Login</button>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="forget-password" class="forget-password">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
        <div class="create-account">
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:;" id="register-btn" class="uppercase">Create an account</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>


<form class="forget-form" method="post" ng-controller="ForgetPassword" ng-submit="passwordGenerator()"> <!-- action="#"-->
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" ng-model="ForgetPassEmailId" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success uppercase btn-block">Reset my password</button> <!--type="submit" -->
        </div>
    </form>

<form class="register-form" action="select_pricing.html" method="post">
        <h3>Create Account</h3>
        <p class="hint">
            Enter your personal details below:
        </p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Full Name</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--ie8, ie9 does not support html5 placeholder, so we just show field title for that-->
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Email Address</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
            <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="password" autocomplete="off" id="register_password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group margin-top-20 margin-bottom-20">
            <label class="check">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tnc" /> I agree to the <a href="#">
        Terms of Service </a> & <a href="#">
        Privacy Policy </a>
            </label>
            <div id="register_tnc_error">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success uppercase btn-block">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The Angular Controller for the  Forget password is as follows

```
 var myApp = angular.module('Login_Upquire_Angular',[]);
 myApp.controller("ForgetPassword",['$scope',function($scope){
   $scope.passwordGenerator=function(){
    var email_id=$scope.ForgetPassEmailId;
       if (email_id=="abc@gmail.com"){
        console.log("Reset Request is accepted");
        window.location="/login.html";
      }
    }
}]);
```

As you can see based on my Angular js File, I want to check whether the given password matches with abc@gmail.com, if yes then it should print on my console "REset Request is accepted" and take me back to login page(/login.html) and to the form element namely login-form. Yet I am getting the following error

```
Cannot POST /login.html
```

Can somebody help me with this? I have tried but couldn't find a solution for it.

Comment: have you tried without the slash? `window.location="login.html"`. Or maybe remove the `method="POST"` attribute from your form. Other I can think of is using `preventDefault` on that form submission. Tell me if any of these worked out

Comment: Why would you want to go back to a page where you already are? You need to asynchronously verify this and handle upon the result of your request.

Comment: @skubski Can you please help me with some references for asynchronous verification part...

Comment: In your case you need to display the form you want (since you have it on a single html page) by using ng-hide/show based on what the user desires. Then when the user submits a form you need to  verify this with a [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) request and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do some asynchronous validation. Something like this: http://www.codelord.net/2014/11/02/angularjs-1-dot-3-taste-async-validators/